# External File reading and writing in Android API 30, in JAVA with MediaStore API

Tags: android, mediastore, android-external-storage

I have some problem with new google policy. I'm trying to find a way to read or write a txt file without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. The problem is:
The MediaStore API can be used to write or read files, but I can only read files created by the application later. In my case, an external software uploads the data to the phone using adb.exe via a USB connection and the app works with this data.
Because it was not created by the app, I get a “FileNotFoundException” “Permission denied” error message for the sample below. What kind of FLAG does the file that the application creates? Can I grant an external file this right?

```
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
            String datfile = null;
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"ac.dat");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,"");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS+dir);
            Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),contentValues);

            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            
            int read = 0;
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                datfile = new String(buffers);
            }

            inputStream.close();
        }
```

Comment: You could the user choose the content via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`. Or, you could modify the script using `adb` to put the content in a better location, such as the location returned by `getExternalFilesDir(null)` on `Context`.

Comment: The .insert() gives you an uri to create a file. Not an uri for an existing file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I don't want the user to select a file because then it won't be comfortable to use

Comment: @blackapps, if I don't use .insert () I can't read the data of a previously created file via URI. What can I use instead?

Comment: Of course you can use the uri of a previously created file again. Anyhow insert() is for a non existing file. Dont tell us that you could use it. Bad idea.

Comment: @blackapps, How should i use the URI for file reading?

Comment: Open an inputstream for it and read. Like you do now. What else?

Comment: if i try to read the file created by an external program with an input stream I get "FileNotFoundException" error and "Permisson Denied" (Android 11). This is the problem